# Pass data between 2 ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to send data from my first ViewController to my second One.

It works fine with a simple Int but with this Double it doesn't work and I don't understand why. So if you can explain why it doesn't work it's cool !

My declaration in first ViewController :

```
var time: Double? = 0.00
```

Then I try to send it to my other ViewController:

```
let vc = segue.destination as! MySecondViewController
   vc.rows = rows[pathForAVC]
   vc.lap = lap[pathForAVC]
   vc.indexPath = pathForAVC
   vc.time = rows[pathForAVC]["Time"]! as! Double
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And my second ViewController:

```
var time: Double? = 0.00
topLabel.text = "\(time!)"
```

N.B:

rows is a Dictionnary:

```
var rows: [[String : AnyObject]] = [[:]]
```

I really don't understand my mistake...

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with passing your value... to me it looks like `rows[pathForAVC]["Time"]` doesn't seem to contain a value and you are force unwrapping it. Try safely unwrapping it using `if let unwrappedTime = rows[pathForAVC]["Time"] as? Double {}`

Comment: There are too much force unwrapping going on there. You should really avoid using it. Ever.

Comment: Additionally if you intend to store `Double`s in your dictionary then its type should really be `[[String : Any]]`. `Double` conforms to `Any` not `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are force unwrapping a value that may not be there:

```
vc.time = rows[pathForAVC]["Time"]! as! Double
```

If `rows[pathForAVC]["Time"]!` is nil, your application will crash. You should *really* avoid using `!` unless your application simply *cannot* continue operating without that value. And those situations should be *rare*.

You should instead safely unwrap your value using an `if let` statement like this:

```
if let unwrappedTime = rows[pathForAVC]["Time"] as? Double {
    print(unwrappedTime)
}
```

(I'm not near Xcode right now but the above code should be close enough to get valuable hints from the compiler).

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now I have understood how to unwrap clearly a value. And it works fine :)